# Htaccess rewrite with parameter value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for some help. I wanted to redirect the following paramters to another url, how can I make this possible? I have googled alot of other solutions but I fail to make this one work.

```
https://(www).website.com/reservation#!/confirm?code=a1XapXsCmlaC0
to
https://new-website.com/test/page#!/confirm?code=a1XapXsCmlaC0
```

```
Attempted code:
RewriteRule \/reservation#!\/confirm\?code=$ https://test.com/$1
```

"grep"-ing the code value would make it much easier.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^reservation/?$ https://test.com/test/page [L,NC,R=301]
```

Query string and fragment i.e. part after `#` will automatically be forwarded to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Where you want to redirect from `(www).website.com` to `new-website.com` in url.

Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://new-%1/test/page#!%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,NE,R=301,L]
```